# How can I use BIP39 private key for encryption?

Tags: encryption, rsa

I want to use user friendly key pair for content encryption. BIP39 mnemonic seems satisfy. But I search a lot and I did not find how to use BIP39/BIP32 key. Is there any algorithm using BIP39/BIP32 key? Or is it possible to convert BIP39/BIP32 key to RSA/ECC key?